# Is it possible to add new columns to powerpoint chart data with excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, excel-charts

I'm looking for a way to modify powerpoint chart data by adding/inserting new columns of data using VBA.
My problem is, every weeky i have an excel data to report with powerpoint slides. I have to follow the evolution of our service over the last four weeks. for example : << if we are on the week5 of work, i have to delete the week1 data and insert the Week5 data.>> I have to do that for many slides and comment everythings on powerpoint. then to do that manually, takes me lot of time. this is why i want to automate it.

**'My VBA Code**

```
Sub managePowerPointChart()
    Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\powerpoint.pptx")


    'Here I could modify a specific cell value
    Set ChartData = oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData
    With ChartData
        .Activate
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value = 2020 'it's okay
        .Workbook.Close
    End With


    'Here i want to insert another column into chart data
    Set ChartData = oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData
    With ChartData
        .Activate
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Columns("E").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Workbook.Close
    End With

    oPPTFile.Close
End Sub
```

[Here a Screenshot to what i want to do by VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Are7H.png)

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What problems are you having?

Comment: Hello BigBen,
my problem is how can i add a new column of data in the chart data.
i can do it manually. But it takes me a lot of time to do that for dozen of slides.
then i want to automate it using vba. Please look at the picture i joined.

thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What happens when you run that script now? Do you get an error? Does it attempt to work but fail in some specific way? Would it be possible to add a sample file that demonstrates what you're trying to do, and has the code in it to test with?

Comment: Hello @Tyler Forsythe, I am a French speaker, perhaps this is why my question is not very clear. 
So, the only thing I need is to add a new column in the chart data. Every week I have a PowerPoint report to edit. I must report the latest 4 weeks operations. For example: the first week (week1) I must calculate the total of transactions and put it in the chart data, in week2/week3/week4 i have to do the same (i joined a picture, please see it).

Comment: But when we arrived on the week5 I have to delete the week1 column and add a new column where I will put the week5 data (then i will only have: week2, week3, week4, week5). And when we arrived on the week6 I have to delete the week2 column and add a new column where I will put the week6 data (then i will only have: week3, week4, week5, week6). the same until week52.
NB: i have many data sources, bigdata (Impala), excel,... that i could access by VBA.
if you don't mind, we can make a video call on hangouts (from 9am to 4pm UTC+0)
I have no error with my code, but it doesn't do what  i need.

Comment: The charts are created directly on PowerPoint, there is no link with an excel sheets or other. Then if you want to modify something you will do it manually on PowerPoint or using VBA. This is why I'm searching the vba solution..